# FullCalendar - difficult to see "late" events in agendaDay view

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar to display events entered by users. As such, I can't control when they are scheduled for.

Strangely, someone has scheduled an event for 11:59pm, and it is basically invisible on FullCalendar's agenda view.

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0tm5cgjb/) for the scenario I'm describing. The JS is copied below:

```
$(function () {
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: false,
        contentHeight: 300,
        defaultView: 'agendaDay',
        scrollTime: '24:00:00',
        allDaySlot: false,
        slotDuration: '00:15:00',
        slotEventOverlap: false,
        forceEventDuration: true,
        defaultTimedEventDuration: '00:30:00',
        displayEventEnd: false,
        editable: false,
        events: [{
            title: 'Earlier (visible) Event',
            start: new Date(y, m, d, 22, 00)
        }, {
            title: 'Late (hard to see) Event',
            start: new Date(y, m, d, 23, 59)
        }]
    });
});
```

As you'll see on JSFiddle, the "Late (hard to see) Event" renders just two pixels tall at the bottom of the calendar, which is unusable. Is there a solution for this? Maybe some way to view the day through 1am the next morning, for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `maxTime: "24:59:59"`. That will extend the agenda view beyond midnight making your event visible. 
Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0tm5cgjb/2/

Comment: Well that was way too easy. Thank you!